# Ignoring crawlers as visitors to website

Tags: php, google-crawlers

When each page loads on my website I use the same php code snipit to add them to a mysql database as new visitors or update the database entry if they already visited. I use cookies to check if the visitor is new or old. However I use the code below to check if its a crawler and not a human before executing my code snipit.

However this does not work. I still get database entries from googlebot and Facebook (so always returns False?). Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function getIsCrawler() {
    $agents = array(
        "Google",
        "google", 
        "facebook", 
        "Facebook", 
        "Bing", 
        "bing",
        "yahoo",
        "Yahoo",
        "Twitter",
        "twitter",
        "Instagram",
        "instagram"
    );
    foreach ($agents as $agent)   
    {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $agent))
        {
            return True;
        }
    }
    return False;
}

$iscrawler = getIsCrawler();

if ($isCrawler == False) 
{
    //run php code snipit to handle visitors
}
```

Comment: Isn't making the site operate different for crawlers supposed to result in a lower page rank on google?

Comment: The google bot still gets to visit the site normally. I just dont want to add it to the database.

Comment: It might be simpler to treat all visitors the same in PHP. Then, in the database, either use a view to eliminate crawlers or use a daily cron job to delete them.

Comment: or just install google analytics and be done with ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you'll probably want to look at. First, you can make this function easier to test by passing values to it. Passing values removes the tight coupling between this function and web pages.

Second, strpos() and its ilk are notorious for their return values. There are [big red (ish) warnings](http://php.net/strpos) in the docs.

Finally, you can reduce the size of the array $agents by using `stripos()`. It's not sensitive to case.

```
function getIsCrawler($external_agent) {
  $agents = array(
                  "Google",
                  "Facebook", 
                  "Bing",
                  "Yahoo",
                  "Twitter",
                  "Instagram",
                  );
  foreach ($agents as $agent)   
    {
      if(stripos($external_agent, $agent) !== False)
        {
          return True;
        }
    }
  return False;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your capitalization is inconsistent on your variable names (i.e. `$iscrawler` vs `$isCrawler`).  Different capitalization = different variable.

To confirm:

```
$X = 5;
$x = 1;
echo '<br/>' . $X;
echo '<br/>' . $x;
```

It prints

```
5
1
```

Comment: Wow can't believe i missed that!